# Display Date based on culture but Time based on a pattern

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting, culture

Does anybody know how to display 
the date of a datetime based on a CurrentCulture but the Time follow this pattern `"HH:mm:ss.fff"` ?

I've tried to use:

DateTime NewDate = DateTime.Now;
NewDate.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
It results: 4-6-2010 14:49:41.
Expected: 4-6-2010 14.49.41,495.

For the Time, I also need to show the miliseconds but the Date format must be still based on the culture.

Comment: Define **doesn't work**, can you post what you're getting vs what you expect?

Comment: I've updated the question. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s = String.Format("{0} {1}", NewDate.ToString("d"), NewDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

If do not wish to use the current culture to format your datestring you can create an instance of CultureInfo and pass it to your ToString method

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string s = String.Format("{0} {1}", NewDate.ToString("d", ci ), NewDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Comment: That's it!! Thank you very much Morten.
just need to add the miliseconds:
string s = NewDate.ToString("d") + " " + NewDate.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");

Comment: great - I have added milliseconds now :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  NewDate.Date.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern) + 
     NewDate.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx):

This method uses formatting information derived from the current culture. In particular, it combines the custom format strings returned by the **ShortDatePattern** and LongTimePattern properties of the DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by the **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat** property